# Problem to output, a user's input after i pass it through a void function (Caesar's Cipher, Java, swing)

Tags: java, swing

I am studying java the last weeks (and rookie). I am trying to code a program, similar to "Caesars Cipher" with my own way (ofcourse not the most efficient algorithm), changing the letters by 2 positions after the "current" letter. I am trying to solve this with the help of swing.

When I test it (eclipse) without GUI everything works properly, for example:

**input**: "i am here." - **output**: "k co jgtg."

But since I am running it through GUI, I am getting **error** in the **actionPerformed** at the end of the code:
*"outputField.**setText**(encryptInput(inputField.getText()));"*

**Error message**: *The method setText() in the type JTextComponent is not applicable for the arguments (void).*

I believe the problem comes from my method "encryptedInput" and its "returning" value. I know as a void returns nothing, but I feel system.out.println() somehow it does not "fit" to my outputField/ActionListener part.

I have checked many topics but unfortunately nothing was helpful. Or at least, my limited programming experience its not helping me to recognize a possible solution from those topics.

I hope can someone help me.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

/* Caesar's Cipher function - 2 positions (indexes) after. */
public class CaesarCipher extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    JLabel inputLabel, outputLabel;
    JButton calculatebtn;
    JTextField inputField, outputField;
    GridLayout grid;
    String encryptedString;

    public CaesarCipher()
    {
        setTitle("Caesar Cipher Converter");        
        setSize(350,200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        inputLabel = new JLabel("Put your Text here : ");
        inputField = new JTextField(20);
        outputLabel = new JLabel("Result : "); 
        outputField = new JTextField(20);
        calculatebtn = new JButton("Convert");

        grid = new GridLayout(5,1);
        JPanel pane = new JPanel();
        pane.setLayout(grid);
        setContentPane(pane);

        pane.add(inputLabel);
        pane.add(inputField);
        pane.add(calculatebtn);
        pane.add(outputLabel);
        pane.add(outputField);

        calculatebtn.addActionListener(this);
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CaesarCipher caeCipher = new CaesarCipher();
        caeCipher.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void encryptInput(String inputString)
    {
        /* Array to calculate the new values (a-z)*/
        char[] caesArray = {'a', 'b', 'c','d','e','f','g','h',
                'i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t',
                'u','v','w','x','y','z', ' ', '.'};

        /* Array for users input */
        char[] inputArray = new char[inputString.length()];
        char resultChar= ' ';

        /* saves the String characters into the inputArray */
        for(int i = 0 ; i < inputArray.length; i++)
        {
            inputArray[i] = inputString.charAt(i);
        }

        for(int i = 0 ; i < inputArray.length ; i++)
            for(int j = 0 ; j < caesArray.length ; j++)
            {

                 if (caesArray[j] == inputArray[i])
                 {
                     /* My special characters */
                     switch(inputArray[i])
                    {
                    case ' ': resultChar = ' ';
                    break;
                    case '.': resultChar = '.';
                    break;
                    }

                    if(inputArray[i] == caesArray[caesArray.length - 1])
                    {
                        inputArray[i] = caesArray[1];
                    }
                    else if(inputArray[i] == caesArray[caesArray.length - 2])
                    {
                        inputArray[i] = caesArray[0];                       
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        resultChar = caesArray[j+2];
                    }
                     System.out.print(resultChar);
                 } 
            }

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
    {

            if(arg0.getSource() == calculatebtn)
            {
                outputField.setText(encryptInput(inputField.getText()));
            }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because:

- your method `encryptInput` does not return anything (return type is `void`)
- and `setText` method accepts a `String` as a parameter

At the end of `encryptInput`, your method is simply printing `resultChar` to the standard output each time you calculate it. You need to change it in order to return a `String` containing the concatenation of all `resultChar`s you're displaying.

There are many ways to do so, here's a simple example, using only the tools you seem to know:

```
public String encryptInput(String inputString)
{
    /* Array to calculate the new values (a-z)*/
    char[] caesArray = {'a', 'b', 'c','d','e','f','g','h',
            'i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t',
            'u','v','w','x','y','z', ' ', '.'};

    /* Array for users input */
    char[] inputArray = new char[inputString.length()];
    char resultChar= ' ';
    char[] resultArray = new char[inputString.length()];

    /* saves the String characters into the inputArray */
    for(int i = 0 ; i < inputArray.length; i++)
    {
        inputArray[i] = inputString.charAt(i);
    }

    for(int i = 0 ; i < inputArray.length ; i++)
        for(int j = 0 ; j < caesArray.length ; j++)
        {

             if (caesArray[j] == inputArray[i])
             {
                 /* My special characters */
                 switch(inputArray[i])
                {
                case ' ': resultChar = ' ';
                break;
                case '.': resultChar = '.';
                break;
                }

                if(inputArray[i] == caesArray[caesArray.length - 1])
                {
                    inputArray[i] = caesArray[1];
                }
                else if(inputArray[i] == caesArray[caesArray.length - 2])
                {
                    inputArray[i] = caesArray[0];                       
                }
                else
                {
                    resultChar = caesArray[j+2];
                }
                 System.out.print(resultChar);
                 resultArray[i] = resultChar;
             } 
        }
    return new String(resultArray);
}
```

P.S.: more generally, this piece of code can definitely be improved, but that would be beyond the scope of that question :)

Comment: You are welcome. Since this helped you in solving your problem, can you please mark this answer as accepted ?

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is, that your encryptInput method doesn't return anything, or rather it returns a void, which is more or less the same. So you should change your code a bit, and change the return datatype to string.

There is also a bit of a hacky way, but If you want you can try that.
You could create a private String variable for the class. Run the encryptInput method and set the private variable to the result of the method. After that, you could set the private variable as the text of the field.

This could then look something like:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

/* Caesar's Cipher function - 2 positions (indexes) after. */
public class CaesarCipher extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

JLabel inputLabel, outputLabel;
JButton calculatebtn;
JTextField inputField, outputField;
GridLayout grid;
String encryptedString;
// ADD THIS VARIABLE
privage String encryptedMessage = "";
//
public CaesarCipher()
{
    setTitle("Caesar Cipher Converter");        
    setSize(350,200);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    inputLabel = new JLabel("Put your Text here : ");
    inputField = new JTextField(20);
    outputLabel = new JLabel("Result : "); 
    outputField = new JTextField(20);
    calculatebtn = new JButton("Convert");

    grid = new GridLayout(5,1);
    JPanel pane = new JPanel();
    pane.setLayout(grid);
    setContentPane(pane);

    pane.add(inputLabel);
    pane.add(inputField);
    pane.add(calculatebtn);
    pane.add(outputLabel);
    pane.add(outputField);

    calculatebtn.addActionListener(this);
}



public static void main(String[] args) {

    CaesarCipher caeCipher = new CaesarCipher();
    caeCipher.setVisible(true);
}

public void encryptInput(String inputString)
{
   this.encryptedMessage = "";
    /* Array to calculate the new values (a-z)*/
    char[] caesArray = {'a', 'b', 'c','d','e','f','g','h',
            'i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t',
            'u','v','w','x','y','z', ' ', '.'};

    /* Array for users input */
    char[] inputArray = new char[inputString.length()];
    char resultChar= ' ';

    /* saves the String characters into the inputArray */
    for(int i = 0 ; i < inputArray.length; i++)
    {
        inputArray[i] = inputString.charAt(i);
    }

    for(int i = 0 ; i < inputArray.length ; i++)
        for(int j = 0 ; j < caesArray.length ; j++)
        {

             if (caesArray[j] == inputArray[i])
             {
                 /* My special characters */
                 switch(inputArray[i])
                {
                case ' ': resultChar = ' ';
                break;
                case '.': resultChar = '.';
                break;
                }

                if(inputArray[i] == caesArray[caesArray.length - 1])
                {
                    inputArray[i] = caesArray[1];
                }
                else if(inputArray[i] == caesArray[caesArray.length - 2])
                {
                    inputArray[i] = caesArray[0];                       
                }
                else
                {
                    resultChar = caesArray[j+2];
                }
                 this.encryptedMessage += resultChar;
             } 
        }

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
{

        if(arg0.getSource() == calculatebtn)
        {
            outputField.setText(encryptInput(inputField.getText()));
        }
}
```

}